# Mensaje de confirmación sweetalert2

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap, sweetalert2

Me encuentro con este problema. Tengo un formulario en html de la siguiente forma:

Al pulsar el botón Registrar Gasto, deseo que se muestre un mensaje de tipo sweetalert2, he investigado y para hacerlo, es necesario hacerlo através de AJAX, bueno tengo la función que lo hace, hasta aquí todo correcto, se muestra el mensaje y pregunta si desean imprimir un recibo o cancelar, despues de pulsar **Imprimir recibo**, se genera el PDF de manera automática, no he logrado que lo realice hasta que pulsen el botón OK de la confirmación, y como tengo un windows location pues el archivo PDF se muestra sin esperar la confirmación del mensaje.

```js
 $(function () {
    
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    
          e.preventDefault();
          
    
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'reg_gasto.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success:
              function mensaje2() {
                swal({
                  title: 'Recibos',
                  text: "Desea Imprimir un Comprobante?",
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  imageUrl: '../../img/print.png',
                  imageWidth: 40,
                  imageHeight: 40,
                  padding: 10,
                  animation: true,
                  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                  confirmButtonText: 'Sí Imprimir'
                }).then(function() {
                  swal(
                    'Imprimir!','Se Envió la impresión.','success'
                  );
                  window.location.href = "http://localhost/pos/conf/reporte.php";
                }
                )
              }
          });
        });
      });
```

```html
<form name="form1" onsubmit="this.reset()">
  <div class="card card-danger">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="card-title">Registro de Gastos</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="detalle" class="form-control" placeholder="Detalle del Gasto">
      </div>

      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="importe" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad de Retiro">
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="card-footer">
      <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger" id="registrar" name="submit" value="Registrar Gasto">
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Espero puedan auxiliarme un poco. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que showCancelButton ya esta deprecado, debes preguntar si se confirmo la impresión y despues mandar llamar el window.location

```
        <script>
              $(function () {    
            $('form').on('submit', function (e) {    
              e.preventDefault();    

              $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'reg_gasto.php',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success:
                  function mensaje2() {
                    swal({
                      title: 'Recibos',
                      text: "Desea Imprimir un Comprobante?",
                      buttons: ["Cancelar", true],
                      imageUrl: '../../img/print.png',
                      imageWidth: 40,
                      imageHeight: 40,
                      padding: 10,
                      animation: true
                    }).then(function(result) {
                      if (result!=null)
                      {
                         swal(
                              'Imprimir!','Se Envió la impresión.','success'
                             ).then(function() {
                                window.location.href = "http://localhost/pos/conf/reporte.php";
                             });
                       }            
                    }
                    )
                  }
              });
            });
          });

        </script>
```

Comment: funciona bien, aunque el botón Cancel no aparece, y si necesito que aparezca antes de mandar a imprimir

Comment: seguro es la versión del js que estas utilizando de sweetalert2 entonces del código que te pase remplaza:

buttons: ["Cancelar", true],

por como lo tenias tu

 showCancelButton: true,

Comment: tenías razón era un conflicto con las versiones. Saludos y muchas gracias!